# access denied for accessing current user email

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, csom

I am getting the following message when running below script :

> "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."

```
var clientContext;
var user;

// Make sure the SharePoint script file 'sp.js' is loaded before your
// code runs.
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);

function sharePointReady() {
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    user = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();

    clientContext.load(user);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
}
function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('The email address of the current user is ' + user.get_email());
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
```

Using sharePoint 2013, not sure what setting I need to change or which line exactly is giving the error.

Having trouble figuring out which line exactly is the problem in console.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone looking, I figured it out. In user permissions make sure remote API is enabled

Comment: Hi @M_kul , good job , and sorry for late answer for your comment , but as i told you in above comments : make sure that the user have at least a read permission  this will include this role "Use Remote Interfaces  -  Use SOAP, Web DAV, the Client Object Model or SharePoint Designer interfaces to access the Web site" , if you do additional setting please add it in details to be useful for all, i also will update my answer with my comment above to be clear for all , thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware of the JavaScript CSOM runs under the context of the current user , and when you get access denied that mean the current context didn't have a sufficient permission ,

So make sure that the current user has a sufficient permission to access your site.

**Note :** you sould assign to the user `at least read as a permission level` that by default have the following role

```
Use Remote Interfaces  -  Use SOAP, Web DAV, the Client Object Model or SharePoint Designer interfaces to access the Web site.
```

I also tried the following code with a user have access to the site at console that working properly ,

```
var clientContext;
var user;

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);

function sharePointReady() {
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    user = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();

    clientContext.load(user);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}
function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('The email address of the current user is ' + user.get_email());
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
```

Regarding **Having trouble figuring out which line exactly is the problem in console**

- Try to add your code to script editor on your page.
- Open your page via google chrome
- press F12 to open developer tools
- Navigate to your source tab
- Set breakpoints to your code as mentioned at [How to set breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/add-breakpoints)

Comment: User does have access to the site. The code runs correctly for an admin but not for normal users. I can't seem to find online what permission exactly I have to change to give users access to this.

Comment: are the normal users have at least read access ?

Comment: Assuming I am granting access to the correct thing yes. After some research I found to have settings for the group so that everyone can see. Which is set. I am in SharePoint designer but I don't see a specific "user" list if there is one

Comment: Apologies I have been able to find the list and indeed I can get to it using _catalogs/users/detail.aspx. But i see no settings for this list. Users do not have access to system pages I do not know if that is what is causing the error.